# How can I disable renaming names of fragments classes during obfuscation?

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-r8, android-obfuscation

Which ProGuard/R8 rules to use?

Currently only Activites aren't renamed

[image]

I need to keep names of Fragment for screens logging as well but the code itself in fragments should be obfuscated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say proguard to keep names for all classes that extend `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` (or another base Fragment class that you use)

```
-keepnames class * extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest you to read this documentation:
https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage#keepoptions

Also use the -keepnames option in your proguard.cfg

I'll give you an example:

```
-keepnames class_specification
```

You could also use this in order to avoid obuscation of any class name:

```
-keepnames class ** { *; }
```

Comment: it will keep names of all classes

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `proguardrules` to keep your directory which contains all the fragments so write below `proguardrules`:

```
-keep public class com.your_app_name.app.view.fragments.** {*;}
```

Ex: My package name is `com.tdscalculator.app` and all my fragments are inside `com -> tdscalculator -> app -> view -> fragments` so for this example I have written above `proguardrule` so modify this rule accordingly.

If you want to keep fragments of different directories then mention all fragments using below `proguardrules`:

```
-keepnames class  com.your_app_name.app.view.fragments.HomeFragment{}
```

Comment: fragments can be placed at difference packages

Comment: Then you have to give all fragments name in keep classes I will modify above answer